# Invalid Java statement

Tags: java

I want to know why the following is invalid in Java. Java compiler says that it is not a valid statement.

```
1+1;
```

I know the following works.

```
int i = 1+1;
```

Please explain why the second one is valid while the first is not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of using `1+1` as a statement? Evaluating 1+1 and simply discarding the result? The compiler doesn't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: I understand that there are no side effects. But you can simply execute a method like: myMethod(); where myMethod is defined as public void myMethod() {}

Comment: `myMethod()` might do something. `1+1` definrely doesn't. Expressions aren't statements in Java, unlike C or C++.

Comment: It's disallowed not because it's an expression. Some expressions, like method calls, are perfectly fine as statements, because they are specifically allowed by the Java syntax. `1+1;` as a statement is not allowed, because it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are doing nothing with `1+1`. That is not a statement, it's an expression that returns a value that should be stored somewhere, like in the second example you give. If your statements have no effect, they are excluded from the language grammar.

Comment: But you can simply execute a method like: myMethod(); where myMethod is defined as public void myMethod() {}

Comment: Well, yes. A call to a void method doesn't return anything. Furthermore, a call to a method is not the same thing as `1+1` as far as the language grammar is concerned, and sure enough, they are treated differently. I don't see the problem here.

Answer (score -2):

The Java syntax needs the variable to be declared like the following

```
Class name = value;
```

You can't create a value without a variable definition and can't create a variable without a name and a class.

Comment: There is no attempt to declare anything here.